# Latex-Suite with TikZ giving errors when compiling new equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, vim, vim-latex

I have a problem using the Latex-Suite package for vim, which only happens when compiling with the TikZ package. The problem comes whenever I try to compile a document when a new labeled equation has been added. When I do this, compiling always brings up this screen:
[image]

The full output is over 5000 lines so I don't include it here, but can link to it if it would be helpful. I can exit out of it using Ctrl+6 and compiling a second time doesn't bring up the screen again, but it always reappears when a new labeled equation is added or if a label is changed. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x=y
  \label{eq:test}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with either the default compiler or latexmk both bring up this screen. I'm assuming this is related to the warning at the bottom of the screen about labels having changed, which appears regardless of whether TikZ is loaded, but doesn't bring up an entirely different screen without TikZ. Is there an way to stop this from happening?

Ideally, I would also like to remove the warning at the bottom of the screen about labels changing. My ignored warnings in my .vimrc is currently:

```
let g:tex_IgnoredWarnings =
    \'Underfull'."\n".
    \'Overfull'."\n".
    \'specifier changed to'."\n".
    \'You have requested'."\n".
    \'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
    \'Label(s) may have changed'."\n".
    \'There were undefined references'."\n".
    \'Citation %.%# undefined'."\n".
    \'Package biblatex Warning'."\n".
    \'Using fall-back BibTeX'."\n".
    \'PDFDocEncoding.'."\n".
    \'Double space found.'."\n"
let g:tex_IgnoreLevel = 12
```

which I thought would prevent this error from occurring, but no such luck.